# Flex - Dynamically add a property to an object based on a string value

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript

I create a new object. My new object will always have a labelField because it has to be added to a dataProvider in a ComboBox. The problem is my next property. Each object in the dataProvider has a dataField property that has a string value [eg: 'code' or 'isoCode']. What I want to be able to do is this:

```
var myObject:Object = new Object;                 // functional
var myOtherObject:Object = new Object;            // functional

myOtherObject[dataField] = "code";                // functional

myObject[labelField] = "Hi";                      // functional
myObject[myOtherObject[dataField].value] = "ALL"; // not functional
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
var myObject:Object = new Object();
var myOtherObject:Object = new Object();

myOtherObject.dataField = "code";

myObject.labelField = "Hi";
myObject[myOtherObject.dataField] = "ALL";
```